# How might I iterate over objects inside an array in proper notation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I read through Javascript The Good Parts, and learned that using `for (i in blah) {}` is bad notation, but the problem is, I'm using `Node.js` and the database I'm using `MongoDB` returns all its queries as `objects` which is fine. Right now I have an ajax query that pulls all information from a table, and I want to do things with each value.

But what the database is returning is an array (with a random size depending on whats in the database) that contains objects, for clarity sake I'll give you an example:

```
[
 {
  'a': 'value of a',
  'b': 'value of b',
  'c': 'value of c'
 },
 {
  'a': 'value of a',
  'b': 'value of b',
  'c': 'value of c'
 }
]
```

How can I iterate through each thing so that I can assign variables from each one this is what I have worked up:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.success.length; i += 1) {
      for(x in data.success[i]) {
        console.log(x);
      }
    }
```

I'm just worried that the bad notation will bite me in the end, I read that the `(blah in blah)` notation doesn't always return results in order. Which this HAS to be in order. Hope I made myself clear, thanks.

I need to get the values, not the name of the variable in the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.keys(data.success[i])` will give you all of the keys present in an object, which you can then `.sort` to guarantee sort order.

```
data.success.forEach(function(item, n) {
   console.log('item ' + n);
   Object.keys(item).sort().forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(key + ':' + item[key]);
   });
});
```

Comment: Using this method, how can I make a loop to assign variables to each value in the object?

Comment: @XCritics: I've updated my answer with a code example iterating over the object from your question. I'd need a clarification on what you mean by assigning variables to each value, though.